# How to install Chart.js in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, chart.js, laravel-6

I want to install Chart.js in my Laravel projects. Using npm install, a config for Webpack, and seeing my index page with some Chart.js examples. On my first try, I got this error in the browser. Maybe I'm not configuring the webpack correctly?

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
> at (index):134

So I copied and pasted this require that I found on Chart.js doc integration.

```
require(['path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.min.js'], function(Chart){
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
});
```

I got this error on `npm run dev`.

> ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError:
> /home/sa/laravelproject/resources/js/app.js: Unexpected token (37:37)
>
> 35 |    36 | require(['path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.min.js'],
> function(Chart){
>
> > 37 |     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
> > |                                      ^   38 | });

Comment: {...} is to indicate you'll need to put options there... try with: var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {});

Comment: Can't you use this library: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#introduction ?

Answer (score 11):

Run this from command line:

```
npm install chart.js
```

Add this line in webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/chart.js/dist/chart.js', 'public/chart.js/chart.js');
```

Then run this from command line:

```
npm run dev
```

In the blade you want the chart on:

```
<script src="{{ asset('chart.js/chart.js') }}"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { 
  ...
  }
</script>
```

Comment: For later versions like 4, the answer below by @ardhiarah will work better.

Answer (score 3):

You can register a global `Chart` variable in `app.js` like this:

```
// Chart JS
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
window.Chart = Chart;
```

And then you can use it in the views or in the other JS files with `new Chart(....)`

Comment: I face issue. I tried your answer & after compile it, when run in browser then it display errors `Invalid scale configuration for scale: xAxes` & `Invalid scale configuration for scale: yAxes`  please help me

Comment: Thanks so much! Adding it to the window object was the winner. Was scratching my head for an hour :)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the some problem.

First I can't bring the library via NPM. I installed it, then I execute "npm run dev". But when I call it in the app it says

```
1:2573 Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at 1:2573
```

If I call it from a CDN, it conflicts with somethig of VUE or Bootstrap. Because it doesn't work. Except that I erase "defer" word from line from app.blade.php:

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

But again, only calling Charts.Js by CDN. Can't bring it from NPM.

Hoping somebody has the same problem. Thank you.
Hernán.

Answer (score 1):

The @Magmatic answer is close.

For newer version like i use v4.x. Revise a bit at:

> mix.copy('node_modules/chart.js/dist/**chart.umd.js**',
> 'public/js/chart.js');

Add another to hide error notice:

> mix.copy('node_modules/chart.js/dist/**chart.umd.js.map**',
> 'public/js/**chart.umd.js.map**');
> mix.copy('node_modules/chart.js/dist/**helpers.js.map**',
> 'public/js/**helpers.segment.js.map**');

Comment: I can confirm this works for version 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this library https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts.

Run...

```
composer require consoletvs/charts
```

Then publish the config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts_config
```

In config/charts.php, specify your chart type:

```
'default_library' => 'Chartjs',
```

Install:

```
npm i chart.js
```

From there follow the instructions on creating a chart.

https://charts.erik.cat/create_charts.html#create-a-chart-class